# Text to column with delimiter within value

Tags: excel

I have to currently deal with a csv file that has the following format:

```
"name","id","number"
```

The problem I am facing is that, for quite a few values, the names have a comma in them which is messing up my "Text to Column" action (since my delimiter is a comma too).

I would like to know if it is possible to easily tell Excel not to look for delimiters inside the quotes to leave the names intact.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Very easy with VBA.......is this approach Okay with you ???

Comment: Use Powerquery maybe, really a single button where you can use `","` as a delimiter? Also, when I try this in O365 at least, Excel seems smart enough to let the comma in a name be so text-to-columns works for me at least. Maybe some sample data is helpfull too here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your messages! Indeed, Excel is smart enough to not find delimiter with quotes. It is just that when I opened my CSV file directly on Excel, the quotes around my names values vanished. But it worked fine when I opened the CSV using the "Get Data from CSV" button.
Sorry for the inconvenience, and thank you for your input!

Answer (score 1):

A VBA approach:

Put all the data in column **A**.  `Select` the cells you want to process and run:

```
Sub Parsee()
    Dim r As Range, sep As String, t As String
    
    sep = Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34)
    
    For Each r In Selection
        t = r.Value
        arr = Split(Mid(t, 2, Len(t) - 2), sep)
        r.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1) = arr
    Next r
        
End Sub
```

The possible disadvantage of this code is it removes the double-quotes:

[image]

If you need all the double-quotes, its an easy fix.